# Excel: SUM values based on date paid or date due with respect to todays date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an excel accounting spreadsheet.

Currently, I have a SUMIF function that adds up the bills due based on =TODAY() (which I have in its own cell, G1),subtracts them from the account balance (I1), and then adds deposits based on the date with respect to todays date (G1).

```
=I1-SUMIF(C2:C6,"<="&G1,B2:B6)+SUMIF(I3:I4,"<="&G1,J3:J4)
```

I have added a column for date paid (D2:D6), as I pay bills earlier than they are typically due. How can I get excel to reference the date paid cells, but when it is empty to reference the respective date due cell? I want to keep the date due cell for reference instead of inputting the date paid into that cell.

I have attempted an IF function, but it either references column D or C only. I don't know how to get it to do C4 if D4 is empty, but still use D1:D3,D5:D6.

I am also using Excel on a Mac.

Comment: Helper column. Hide it if you like. `=IF(AND(NOTBLANK(C2),C2<$G$1),C2,$G$1)` and reference that in your `SUMIF`.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and upload some sample data (screen shot ), will  help us to fix the issue !